# Typed Complex Criteria Query with Java Hiberate EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager

I am generally unfamiliar with Java, Hibernate, or EntityManager. I've used NHibernate a good amount but with Linq and Fluent NHibernate there is hardly any need to use the criteria api so I'm kind of floundering trying to get the following query to work

> Get all instances of ReferenceCodeMetaData where siteId == 1 and
>   codeType == 'sampleUnits'

I know it should be something along the lines of

```
em.createQuery(Restrictions.and(
  Restrictions.eq("siteId", siteId),
  Restrictions.eq("codeType", codeType)
))
```

But I cannot get the generic typing correct. Can someone help me fill in the body of this function?

```
public ReferenceCodeMetaData[] getMatching(EntityManager em, Integer siteId, String codeType) {

  return ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using method in EntityManager that takes CriteriaQuery or JPQL query as argument, but type of your argument types refers to Hibernate Criteria. Here is three possible implementations for such a method:

```
public ReferenceCodeMetaData[] getMatchingWithJPQL(EntityManager em,
                                                   Integer siteId,
                                                   String codeType) {
    String jpql =  "SELECT r FROM ReferenceCodeMetaData r where siteId = :siteId AND codeType = :codeType";
    TypedQuery<ReferenceCodeMetaData> query = em.createQuery(jpql, ReferenceCodeMetaData.class);

    query.setParameter("siteId", siteId);
    query.setParameter("codeType", codeType);
    List<ReferenceCodeMetaData> result = query.getResultList();

    return result.toArray(new ReferenceCodeMetaData[result.size()]);
}

public ReferenceCodeMetaData[] getMatchingWithCriteriaAPI(EntityManager em,
                                                          Integer siteId,
                                                          String codeType) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ReferenceCodeMetaData> cq = cb.createQuery(ReferenceCodeMetaData.class);
    Root<ReferenceCodeMetaData> root = cq.from(ReferenceCodeMetaData.class);

    cq.select(root)
        .where(cb.and(
            cb.equal(root.get("siteId"), cb.parameter(Integer.class, "siteId")),
            cb.equal(root.get("codeType"), cb.parameter(String.class, "codeType"))));

    TypedQuery<ReferenceCodeMetaData> query = em.createQuery(cq);

    query.setParameter("siteId", siteId);
    query.setParameter("codeType", codeType);
    List<ReferenceCodeMetaData> result = query.getResultList();
    return result.toArray(new ReferenceCodeMetaData[result.size()]);
}

public ReferenceCodeMetaData[] getMatchingWithJHibernateCriteria(EntityManager em, 
                                                                 Integer siteId, 
                                                                 String codeType) {
    HibernateEntityManager hem = em.unwrap(HibernateEntityManager.class);
    Session session = hem.getSession();
    // If you use some older version of Hibernate, then unwrap method is not 
    // available and you can use following instead of two lines above:
    // Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();


    List<ReferenceCodeMetaData> result = session.createCriteria(ReferenceCodeMetaData.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("siteId", siteId) )
        .add(Restrictions.eq("codeType", codeType))
    .list();
    return result.toArray(new ReferenceCodeMetaData[result.size()]);
}
```

First two are standard JPA and last one is Hibernate specific. All of them generate equivalent SQL-query and produce then same result. I would go for first one in this case.

Comment: Oh thank god +100, finally someone who really knows this stuff. Can I just borrow your brain for a while?